# How to set the axis of blender so that it is consistent with the rotation direction of the sensor？

Tags: 3d-view, coordinates, quaternion

I am a beginner in blender. I use the serial port to connect the posture sensor with the blender.  Now I have a problem: I rotate sensor around the Z axis, but in blender it rotates around the Y axis.  Let the sensor rotate around the Y axis, but in blender it rotates around the Z axis.  But rotate around the X axis is correct.  I am using quaternion to control the bones. So, what should I change?

This is a gif of rotating the sensor around the Z axis
[image]
This is a gif of rotating the sensor around the Y axis
[image]
This is a gif of rotating the sensor around the X axis
[image]
and this is my sensor:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a duplicate of the bone, in pose mode hover over the W quaternion value of the original bone, right click and choose "Copy as new driver", then select the new bone, hover over its W Quat value, right click and choose "Paste driver.

Repeat for X values.

Repeat for Y and Z inverting the values (paste Y on Z and Z on Y).

Then you can hide the first bone and use the new one.

[image]

Comment: This method can solve the problem :D. But  this means that I will assign the value of the Y-axis to the Z-axis. Does this make sense?

Comment: I don't know.. would parenting to a reoriented Empty give you transforms in the Empty's space?

Comment: It's just about naming conventions in the information chain, but you will assign the Y values you want on Y axis. Names are just names. There may be some cases in which you will need inverted values: in this case just edit the driver as scripted expression and add a minus sign in front of the variable.